# Ruby 'aws-sdk' how to get the bucket instance

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to get objects list from S3 buckets so I need to create Aws::S3::Bucket.
But, I could not know how to create it by looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html.
The document do not have the description as far as I look at.
If anyone know the way, please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: It's under "initialize"

Comment: Oh, thank you. I missed the section.. Thank your help!